# UIImagePickerController - tapping the Album TableView or Selecting Album causes table to go blank? iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios5, uiimagepickercontroller, uipopovercontroller

I'm trying to reproduce a Similar Media Picker that is like the one in Pages. Within a `UIPopoverController` There is a `UISegmentedControl` that selects different media Types. One of the SegmentedControls I have is Labeled Images. I want to be able to select that Segment and have the view below present the ImagePicker.

I'm Close. I have a few issues. When presenting the VC, I get: 
 [image: Popover with ImagePicker]

I get the Following in the Debugger:
`UIStatusBarStyleBlackTranslucent is not available on this device.`  Not sure where that is coming from. I've tried with and without:

```
        imagePicker.modalInPopover = YES;
        imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
```

Though I still cannot get it to work Right.  It Presents just fine. I see the `UISegmentedControl` I see my other Media Pages, I click the Image segment and I see the ImagePicker, Title is 'Photos' Has a Cancel Button I need to get rid of, and shows the two Albums I have on the device.

If I tap anywhere in the TableView (on an album or not), the two Albums go away. The NavBar and Cancel button are still there, though no Albums anymore. Tapping an Album Highlights the Row, though does not show the Images within the Album.

[image: Popover after tapping image Picker]

The other odd part of my code is that the Delegate for the Image Picker is the VC that Presented the UIPopoverController. Not sure if that plays into it.  When I do hit the Cancel Button, I get:

```
-[PLUILibraryViewController performSelector:withObject:withObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance
```

Here is my Code to present the Picker.

```
- (void) setupImagePicker {

    IoScreenEditorViewController * ioScreenEditorViewController = (IoScreenEditorViewController *)[UIAppDelegate.ioMainViewController currentViewController];
    ioScreenEditorViewController.elementSelectedFromList = [elementsForPage objectAtIndex:0];
        // Show an image picker to allow the user to choose a new photo.
    UIImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    imagePicker.delegate = ioScreenEditorViewController;
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = NO;
    NSArray * ourMediaTypes = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: (NSString *) kUTTypeImage, nil];
    [imagePicker setMediaTypes: ourMediaTypes];
    [ourMediaTypes release];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera]) {
            //  imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
        imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    } else {
        imagePicker.sourceType =  UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    }

    [imagePicker.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 340, 500)]; // just for testing

        //imagePicker.modalInPopover = YES;
        //imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
   [self.view addSubview:imagePicker.view];

    [imagePicker release];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed the class type that the Picker was being called from to a `UIViewController` and then altered the presentation code to look like this:

```
    imagePicker.modalInPopover = YES;
    imagePicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;
    [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:NO  completion:^{  }];
```

I still get the Cancel Button, though the Image Picker does seem to be working like it should.

Comment: Did you still not get the cancel button to be hidden? Check out this post: https://devforums.apple.com/thread/186865

Answer (score 0):

Although I was also as of yet unable to hide the Cancel button of the picker, I would suggest you revise how you are presenting it.

As an effort to get help from the community of iOS developers about this, I've made a sample project, please go and download it. In the project you can see that I am using view controller containment in order to get the picker on screen.

This may perhaps be a better way for you do do this too?

https://bitbucket.org/danielphillips/image-picker-demo